# TypeScript error, declare but its value is never read

Tags: jquery, typescript

```
private tree_widget: ITreeWidget;
private $ghost: JQuery | null;
private drag_element: DragElement | null;
private previous_ghost: IDropHint | null;
private open_folder_timer: number | null;

constructor(tree_widget: ITreeWidget) {
    this.tree_widget = tree_widget;

    this.hovered_area = null;
    this.$ghost = null;
    this.hit_areas = [];
    this.is_dragging = false;
    this.current_item = null;
}
```

The above is my code but I am getting the error when I build the app in visual studio 2017

Comment: What is the exact error, what line does it occur on ? Do you use the value of member/field being flagged by the compiler ?

Comment: what if you change it to: ```constructor(treeWidget: ITreeWidget) { this.tree_widget = this.treeWidget }```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems regarding this class declaration:

`hovered_area`, `hit_areas`, `is_dragging`, `current_item`,  are not declared as class properties (or maybe I can't see them because you didn't include code of the full class).

Regarding the error " is declared but never read", `tsc` is notifying that the variable is never accessed: it is declared, assigned a value, but **never used**.